# How can I correctly configure my tsconfig.json so only the files necessary are required when using npm run build?

Tags: javascript, typescript, libraries, helper, tsconfig

**Overview**

I have a helper function library that I want to import into my projects.

**Question**

How can I correctly configure my tsconfig.json so only the files necessary are required when using npm run build? I don't want any extra files in to be included.

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "declaration": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

**Included in `package.json`**

```js
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
```

**What's showing in `node_modules` when imported into a project**

1. Should `src` be showing??
2. How can I remove `jest.config.js`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tsconfig.json` file doesn't have anything to do with what ends up in the final npm package. Per default (more or less) everything that is contained in your project directory will also be added into your package (except the `node_modules` folder).

There are two ways to control the contents of your package

1. Create a file named `.npmignore` and add every file/folder you want to be *excluded* from your package. This works similar to the `.gitignore` file. See the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) for details.
2. You can add a `files` array to your `package.json` and add all files/folders you want to be *included* in your package. See [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#files) for details.

What files need to be in your package, depends on the functionality your package provides. The test configuration probably isn't required for the final package, neither is the source ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude some files from your NPM package specify list of them in `.npmignore` file. This way when you publish a new version of the package excluded file will disappear from you node_modules.

Also, if you use yarn, you can specify the list of files you want to remove after installing packages in the `.yarnclean` file. But this way files will be deleted from all packages in node_modules.

If you haven't publish your package and use it with `npm link` or `yarn link`, you can't remove file from node_modules.

In fact, you can specify all the files in the package except `dist`, `package.json` and `REAMDE.md`